# Use premade array as categories in wp_query?

Tags: categories, wp-query, array

I have a theme options panel that the user can set which categories they want to use which is then saved as an array $blog_cat[0] etc.  They can select as many categories as they want for the array and it saves the category number not slug.

I am having trouble when I go to make a wp_query using these settings.  How can I take that array and use it in the wp_query?

If I use the following bit of code it will output all of the categories:
$catnum = 0;
foreach($blog_cat as $blogcats) {echo $blog_cat[$catnum]; $catnum++;}

However, I can't use this in the actual wp_query which looks like this:

$wp_query = new WP_Query('category_name=' . $blog_cat . '&showposts=3');

I can target them individually but not dynamically regardless of how many are set.

I'm guessing this isn't a very hard problem to fix but I don't know enough about the syntax to figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the category__in parameter and that will do exactly what you're looking for.

[Codex: WP_Query - Category Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Comment: Would I just use the variable $blog_cat or how will I make it run through all of the array?

Comment: Yes, you would just use the variable if it is an array.